# Proving that $2\delta\sin(x)-\sin((N+1)x)+\delta^2\sin((N-1)x)=0$, for $N>1$ and $\delta\in[0,1]$, has real solutions

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

We have the equation

\begin{equation}
2\delta\sin(x)-\sin((N+1)x)+\delta^2\sin((N-1)x) = 0,
\end{equation}
where $N$ is a positive integer greater than $1$ and $\delta\in[0,1]$.

Now, numerical studies indicate that the solutions to this equation are always real, but we have not been able to prove it. One idea was to use [Rouche's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem), but that would require us to know about the number of real solutions in e.g. the interval $[0,\pi]$, and it seems hard to implement anyway since the equation has three terms. Another idea was to rewrite the equation in a convenient way, let $x = a+bi$ and see that the only way to have the right hand side be a real number, was to put $b=0$, but that just generated another equation that was hard to solve. Finally, we tried to argue in the following way: We know that for $\delta=0$, the equation has only real solutions, and we know the number of them. If we increase $\delta$ and show that the maxima of the curve $\sin((N+1)x)+\delta^2\sin((N-1)x)$ in the interval $[0,\pi]$ lie above the curve $2\delta\sin(x)$ for all $\delta$ (or precisely on the curve for $\delta=1$), we will not "lose" any real solutions. But analyzing the maxima was not so straightforward either.

Comment: Previous comment is now start of my answer. I used a more geometric argument to justify the claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply with $\sin((N+1)x)$, that only adds known real roots to the equation. Then
$$
(\sin((N+1)x)-δ\sin x)^2=δ^2[\sin((N−1)x)\sin((N+1)x)+\sin^2x)
\\
=\frac{δ^2}2[\cos(2x)-\cos(2Nx)+1-\cos(2x)]=δ^2\sin^2(Nx)
$$
Now it remains to show that the two remaining equations
\begin{align}
2\sin\left(\frac{N+1}2x\right)\cos\left(\frac{N+1}2x\right)
&=\sin((N+1)x)
\\
&=δ\left[\sin x\pm\sin(Nx)\right]
\\
&=\pm2δ\sin\left(\frac{N\pm1}2x\right)\cos\left(\frac{N\mp1}2x\right)
\end{align}
only have real solutions. Removing factors with only real roots (corresponding to the factor that was added at the start) results in the two equations
\begin{align}
\sin\left(\frac{N+1}2x\right)&=-δ\sin\left(\frac{N-1}2x\right)
\\
\cos\left(\frac{N+1}2x\right)&=δ\cos\left(\frac{N-1}2x\right)
\end{align}

---

Both equations, after shifting and rescaling the argument, have the form
$$
\sin(z)=δq(z)
$$
where from the sinusoid properties of $q$ we only need to use that  it is real, $q(\bar z)=\overline{q(z)}$, and bounded by $1$ on the real axis, $q(x)\in[-1,1]$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$.

Now remember that the Rouché theorem implies that the root number (with multiplicities) is constant under variation of $δ$ in every regularly bounded open set, the set of roots itself continuous, continuous arcs with branching and intersection points. Further, $f_δ(z)=\sin(z)-δq(z)$ is real, $f(\bar z)=\overline{f(z)}$, so that non-real roots only occur in conjugate complex pairs.

$f_0(z)=\sin z$ only has real roots at $z_k=k\pi$. It is now easy to show that for $|δ|<1$ the values $f_δ(z_k\pm\frac\pi2)$ are real and have opposing signs, implying a real root inside the interval $[z_k-\frac\pi2,z_k+\frac\pi2]$. This means that the different branches of root curves starting from $z_k$ at $δ=0$ can not intersect for $|δ|<1$, which makes the branching-off of a non-real complex-conjugate pair impossible. By continuity, all the roots for  $|δ|=1$ still remain real.

Comment: And then, in the last paragraph, the argument is that we have at least one root in each of the intervals for all $\delta$, but since we know exactly which these are for $\delta=0$, and since we know that the number of roots within any open set is constant when we change $\delta$, we cannot get more roots than we had for $\delta=0$ and thus there will be exactly one real root in each of the intervals. And these will be the only roots we have, since it is limited by the number of roots of $f_{0}(z)$.

Comment: Just trying to fill in some details here. When you say that Rouché's theorem implies that the number of roots is constant in any open set for all $\delta$, does this come from the fact that $|f_{\delta_1}(z)-f_{\delta_2}(z)|<|f_{\delta_1}(z)|+|f_{\delta_2}(z)|$? How do you get the strict inequality? I only get $LHS = |\delta_1-\delta_2||q(z)| = |\sin(z)/q(z)-\sin(z)/q(z)+\delta_1-\delta_2||q(z)|\leq |f_{\delta_1}(z)|+|f_{\delta_2}(z)|$ for all $z$ (unless $q(z)=0$, but in that case we trivially have $|f_{\delta_1}(z)-f_{\delta_2}(z)| \leq  |f_{\delta_1}(z)|+|f_{\delta_2}(z)|$.).

Comment: I should have said in every bounded open set. Note that the inequality only needs to hold on the boundary, and that one chooses the set so that there are no roots on the boundary for the reference value of $δ$. Then $|f_{\delta_1}(z)|+|f_{\delta_2}(z)|$ will have a positive minimum and $|f_{\delta_1}(z)-f_{\delta_2}(z)|$ can be made smaller than this on this compact boundary.

Comment: And yes to the first, the single roots can not leave the real line and remain well-separated for the small values of $δ$, an event where there is a real double root that then splits into a conjugate pair can only happen for $|δ|\ge 1$.

Answer (score 2):

As per @Lutz comment, trigonometric manipulations reduce the problem to proving that:

$\sin((N+1)x)=δ[\sin x\pm\sin(Nx)]=2δ\sin\left(\frac{N\pm1}2x\right)\cos\left(\frac{N\mp1}2x\right)$ has only real solutions.

Case 1: $\sin((N+1)x)=δ[\sin x+\sin(Nx)]$ or $\sin\left(\frac{N+1}2x\right)\cos\left(\frac{N+1}2x\right)=\delta\sin\left(\frac{N+1}2x\right)\cos\left(\frac{N-1}2x\right)$ and ignoring the roots of $\sin\left(\frac{N+1}2x\right)=0$ which are real, we need to prove that:

$\cos\left(\frac{N+1}2x\right)=\delta\cos\left(\frac{N-1}2x\right)$ has only real roots for any $0 \le \delta \le 1$

Rewriting the above as $e^{i(N+1)x}+1=\delta (e^{iNx}+e^{ix})$ and putting $z=e^{ix}$ (and using that $x \in \mathbb R$ iff $|e^{ix}|=1$) the problem reduces to showing that:

$(P_{\delta}(z))=P(z)=z^{N+1}-\delta(z^N+z)+1$ has roots only on the unit circle.

But clearly $P$ is $(N+1)$ self-inversive (which means $P^*(z)=z^{N+1}\overline{P(\frac{1}{\bar z})}=P(z)$ or equivalently $a_{N+1-k}=\bar a_k, P(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{N+1} a_kz^k$), so by general theory we have that $P$ has all roots on the unit circle iff $P'$ has all its roots inside the closed unit disc (we will give a short proof of this at the end)

A simple computation gives $P'(z)=(N+1)z^N-\delta N z^{N-1}-\delta$ and the triangle inequality immediately shows that $|z|>1$ (so $|z^N|>1, |z|^N>|z|^{N-1}$) implies $|P'(z)| >0$ since $|\delta| \le 1$ so we are done!

Case 2: $\sin((N+1)x)=δ[\sin x-\sin(Nx)]$

Now (ignoring the real roots of $\cos\left(\frac{N+1}2x\right)=0$), we need to prove:

$\sin\left(\frac{N+1}2x\right)=-\delta\sin\left(\frac{N-1}2x\right)$ has only real roots for any $0 \le \delta \le 1$.

With $z=e^{ix}$ this translates to $Q(z)=z^{N+1}+\delta(z^N-z)-1$ has roots only on the unit circle.

If $N$ even that $Q(-z)=P_{-\delta}(z)$ so we are done by case 1 (where we showed that we only need $|\delta| \le 1$).

If $N$ is odd, pick $\omega^{N+1}=-1$ a non trivial root of $-1$ and then:

$Q_1(z)=Q(\omega z)=-z^{N+1}+\delta(-\bar \omega z^N-\omega z)-1$ is self inversive.

It follows that the proof in case $1$ goes through using the triangle inequality to show that $|z|>1$ implies $|Q_1'(z)|>0$ so the roots of $Q_1$ hence of $Q$ are all on the unit circle and we are done!

Lemma: $P$ of degree $N$ self-inversive ($a_{N-k}=\bar a_k, P(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{N} a_kz^k$), then $P$ has all the roots on the unit circle iff $P'$ has all the roots inside the closed unit disc (note that by definition $P(0) \ne 0$ since $P$ has actual degree $N$)

Let $R(z)=\frac{zP'(z)}{NP(z)-zP'(z)}=\frac {zP'(z)}{(zP'(z)^*)} $ (where as before $Q^*(z)=z^{N}\overline{Q(\frac{1}{\bar z})}$ for a degree $N$ polynomial, while the above equality follows from the fact that $P$ is self inversive). In particular if $z_k, k=1,..m-1, m \le N$ are the roots of $P'/P$ one gets by a simple computation that $R(z)=cz\Pi_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{z-z_k}{1-\bar z_k z}, |c|=1$ so if $P'$ (hence $P'/P$ too) has roots only inside the closed unit disc (actually the above compuation shows that the roots of $P'$ on the unit circle are roots of $P$ too so they are not among the $z_k$), we have that $R$ is a Blaschke product with $R(0)=0$ so in particular a unit disc self-map, hence $R(z) \ne -1, |z|<1$.

But $\frac{zP'(z)}{P(z)}=\frac{NR(z)}{1+R(z)}$ so $R(z) \ne -1, |z|<1$ implies $P$ cannot have roots inside the open unit disc. As $P$ self inversive means that roots come in pairs $z, 1/\bar z$, it follows that $P$ can't have roots outside the unit circle either, and we are done with the lemma as the converse is trivial from the above computations.